# PySpark RDD Filter with "not in" for multiple values

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD looks like below:

```
myRDD:
[[u'16/12/2006', u'17:24:00'], 
[u'16/12/2006', u'?'],
[u'16/12/2006', u'']]
```

I want to exclude the records with '?' or '' in it.
Following code works for one by one filtering, but is there a way to combine and filter items with '?' and '' in one go to get back following:

```
[u'16/12/2006', u'17:24:00']
```

The below works only for one item at a time, how to extend to multiple items

```
myRDD.filter(lambda x: '?' not in x)
```

want help on how to write:

```
myRDD.filter(lambda x: '?' not in x && '' not in x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
myRDD.filter(lambda x: ('?' not in x) & ('' not in x))
```

Comment: Works, Thanks Suresh